# MS Access: Access time

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am working on a MS Access 2010 multi-user application. Intended as one user opens a screen(Form) that the second user cannot open the same screen(Form) at the same time and so receive a warning.

I have noticed that access wait 2 seconds before opening the screen(Form) when  the first user clicked the Form open button. In this way can the second user open the same screen. How can I control the access time of screen actually? 
is there some setting I can use to control the access time?
Thanks,

Comment: Weird use I must say - but yiu could probably handle this by creating a "lock table" on your backend database. When the form is opened add code in the Form_Open event to check the table for a "lockedBy = True" record. If not there then update the current record with currentusername and locked by =true

Comment: If 2 users cannot open the same form at the same time, it's not really a multi-user applicationm right  ? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am slightly confused as to the purpose of having a multi-user application that a form can only be opened by one user at a time.  Or, are you trying to say that only one user can access a particular record for editing at a time?

If you are trying to prevent multiple people from editing the same record at once, there is a 'use record locks' property within access that prevents multiple people from accessing the same record at a time - but you will run into issues with someone leaving their computer with the record pulled up, and no one can get into that record until they have closed out.

In whichever case your using, you can use a form timer event to check for idle time if the user is not doing anything and force them to close.  If you are trying to present a message to the user that is not in the record yet, you can check for the record locked error code, and present a custom message to them when attempting to open it.

I would recommend putting a sample of your file up if you can so i can get a better understanding of what you are trying to do.